# Proof involving indices of integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $$\operatorname{ind}_gab\equiv \operatorname{ind}_ga + \operatorname{ind}_gb\pmod{p-1} $$

Where
$$g^t \equiv k\pmod p \text{ if and only if } t \equiv \operatorname{ind}_gk \pmod{p-1}$$

I'm not really sure where to start with this. I've tried setting both sides as congruent to $r$ so that I have $g^r \equiv ab \pmod p$ but I can't think of where to go from there.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! New users are recommended to browse the "help" pages via the link in the upper right by the "search" field. In particular, we recommend you read the "asking" help pages at http://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking. You are likely to receive more prompt and targeted responses if you tell us how you've attempted to solve the problem, and where you are getting stuck. Also, your notation may not be standard; you should include definitions of your notation and variables so others can understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

The set-up here tacitly assumes that $g$ is a generator of the nonzero residues mod $p$, where $p$ is a prime.  Note that

$$g^{\operatorname{ind}_ga}\equiv a\pmod p\quad\text{and}\quad g^{\operatorname{ind}_gb}\equiv b\pmod p$$

Now let $t={\operatorname{ind}_ga}+{\operatorname{ind}_gb}$.  Then

$$g^t=g^{{\operatorname{ind}_ga}+{\operatorname{ind}_gb}}=g^{{\operatorname{ind}_ga}}g^{{\operatorname{ind}_gb}}\equiv ab\pmod p$$

hence $t\equiv {\operatorname{ind}_gab}\pmod{p-1}$, which is what we were asked to prove.